# Bootstrap the grid breaks when the text is large

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I been facing this problem several times and I couldn't find a proper solution.
Basically I have a bootstrap grid with 2 columns side by side with text (and lets say 4 rows). 
If one of the items in the grid has a large text the grid breaks and doesn't show the following element in the right position.

[Here is the example](http://www.bootply.com/AtpMvAFkdE) . You can see that it breaks under Phone Support (if you see it in a col-md > screen)

My solution was to set the min-hight of the item as the max-height of the larger text, and in that way it works, but it is not the optimal solution.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set class clear fix after your elements

and you can set in your medias that which one set in a row

for example

```css
//sass file

//this code set two element in a row

.clearfix{
  &:nth-of-type(n){
    display: none;
  }

  &:nth-of-type(4n){
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="" alt="" />
      </a>      
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">           
      <a href="#">
        <img src="" alt="" />
      </a>         
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, this works, thank you Hossein. Could you explain how does it work? Does restart the height after each row?

Comment: thanks Gonzalo, in this model each col-* can be different height in rows it means if you have different heights in your col-* in a row the order of the other rows does not effected on other. if you want more info about this i can edit the answer and explain more in my answer

Comment: Sure if you have time and you can comment I think it will be useful for other people, since in this case I have 3 cols but I would like to understand how it changes if I have 2, 4, etc. Thanks